# Use raft pattern instead of wall

Tags: ultimaker-cura, rafts

This might be an odd question, as rather than being disappointed by the raft material that Cura produces, I actually love it.

It prints quickly, is sturdy yet flexible...

I was wondering whether anyone knew of a way to make the walls / base of a print use the raft patterning? Is there a strategy for using this kind of material in CAD apps, or has anyone tried implementing a plugin for Cura to turn all walls into rafts?

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE. Could you add an image of the pattern? Rafts aren't often used, but remembering the pattern I think this is already available in Cura as infill, not sure what you mean by walls. An image of what you mean might help out to make the question more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cura, like many slicers, allows one to set the number of passes for top, bottom and sides. By setting these values to zero, your model becomes completely and only infill. The pattern selection for infill allows you to choose the design which would appeal to you and possibly match that of the raft.

I've just now imported a mostly monolithic STL file and tested the above. By varying the percentage of infill, various patterns result. Low infill percentage values make for a mostly empty print, while the higher numbers provide attractive geometric results.

Of course, one would want the original model to have sufficient wall thickness to create the objective.

Comment: excellent idea! Unfortunately my printer's motherboard recently gave up the ghost, but once I've resurrected it I'll definitely give it a go! Thanks